# Command Line Tools fail to install OS X Lion 10.7.3 Xcode 4.3

Tags: macos, command-line, xcode

I'm trying to install the command line tools to get gcc, make, and other goodies after a Lion upgrade. I went to Preferences → Downloads in Xcode and attempted to install the command line tools. At the end of the installation, an error box appears with the following message:

> The package “BluetoothSDK.pkg” is untrusted.

When I open up a terminal window and try to run gcc, the command is still not found.

Does anyone know why the Apple Developer Tools installer is broken?

Comment: Hmm - that could be the cause, but have you had a look at the installation log? When installer is running, you can type command+L and command+3 to show both the log window and all log messages. Perhaps some additional data will help us help you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just in case anybody comes here after me, I will leave an answer. I found that you can install the command line tools using a separate .dmg file at this link:

https://developer.apple.com/downloads/?=command%20line%20tools

Comment: When installing now (it's July 2016), a warning of an expired certificate is prompted upon install and can be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at `/var/log/system.log` just after the attempt to install the command line tools from within Xcode, here is the error message you get:

```
May  1 19:50:13 ••My_Mac•• Xcode[4711]: [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/IDEKit/IDEKit-2113/Framework/Classes/Downloadables/IDEDownloadablesActivityReporter.m:76
        Details:  Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=102 "The package “BluetoothSDK.pkg” is untrusted." UserInfo=0x400c91e00 {NSLocalizedDescription=The package “BluetoothSDK.pkg” is untrusted., NSURL=file://localhost/private/var/folders/b5/1x0nn19j48l8x21shmcppq3m0000gn/T/attached-image-785d03d028219ec5426def5c3a84ea4de0c91e9e/Command%20Line%20Tools%20(Lion)/Packages/BluetoothSDK.pkg, PKInstallPackageIdentifier=com.apple.pkg.BluetoothSDKLeo, NSUnderlyingError=0x401ec3900 "The operation couldn’t be completed. CSSMERR_TP_CERT_EXPIRED"}
        Object:   
        Method:   +initialize
        Thread:   {name = (null), num = 1}
        Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
```

This error message means that the certificate signing `BluetoothSDK.pkg`
is expired.

An independant version of the Command line Tools may be downloaded from here:
[Download for Apple Developers](https://developer.apple.com/downloads)
by searching for "Command Line Tools (OS X Lion)" and selecting the last one (Apr 15, 2013):
[image: Command Line Tools (Os X Lion)]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the install in preferences, you can change the date for 2012 and it works :).

You **do** have to start the install with an accurate date first, or else you will get an error about an invalid server.  So bring up time preferences, click install in xcode, then within 30 seconds adjust the year in time preferences.  Then install succeeds.

Comment: Woah - so it's just that one cert bundled in the package has "now expired" but it otherwise good to go? If so, great work @leorleor and jojo