# Installing Xcode command line tools error: The package “DeveloperToolsCLI.pkg” is untrusted

Tags: macos, xcode, install

When I try to install the Xcode Command Line Tools I get the error message: "The package “DeveloperToolsCLI.pkg” is untrusted." I can't seem to find the answer to this problem anywhere, how do you fix this?

Comment: Where did you get the package from?

Comment: Does http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44135/command-line-tools-fail-to-install-osx-lion-10-7-3-xcode-4-3 help?

Comment: I installed the package from Xcode>Preferences>Downloads

Answer (score 3):

Probably the certificate is outdated. To circumvent this the following procedure should work:

- Open "System Preferences"
- Hit "Security & Privacy"
- Hit the tab "General"
- Click the lock and enter your admin password
- at "Allow applications from anywhere" mark the radio button "Anywhere"
- then click the button "Allow from anywhere"

[image: sec]

or like indicated in the screenshot above control-click individual apps/installer-apps and select "Open". This probably doesn't work for the DeveloperToolsCLI.pkg but for other apps.

Comment: I had already done exactly this a while back and somehow OS X set it back to "Mac App Store" without my consent.  Also, this didn't work.  Downloading and installing from link below in @Damian Nikodem's answer worked.

Answer (score 2):

Funnily Enough I had the exact same issue as you did about 10 minutes ago and stumbled across here via google.

I still had issues after relaxing the code signing checks on OSX also.

I logged into https://developer.apple.com/downloads and downloaded the CLI package from there (then installed them directly. )

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by changing the date, [klanomath's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/173730/146393) didn't work for me.

Seems like the problem is trusting the certs, so being Sept 2015, I started to download the tools and **only after the download had started** changed the date to Sept 2013 in the Date & Time dialog of the System Preferences.

You cannot change the date before the download starts, otherwise it will say the source is not trusted.

Comment: Bahahaha this is genius. Also, it's funny how they autoupdate tools, but not certificates. Defeats the whole purpose of the autoupdating